# Class level lock for static variables in java

Tags: java, multithreading, locks

If i don't use any setters/getters in my java class X. When a thread A has class level lock of my class X. Can another thread B change my static variable directly ??

```
public class X {

    Integer static_variable = 10;

    public static void doNothing {
        /* Do Nothing */
    }

}
```

Lets say thread A has class level lock now.  Can i do X.static_variable = 11 from another thread B?

I was writing a code to get deadlock in java.

public class A implements Runnable {

```
    public static Integer as = 5;
    static A a = new A();
    static B b = new B();

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO code application logic here

    Thread thread1 = new Thread(a);
    Thread thread2 = new Thread(b);
    thread1.setName("First");
    thread2.setName("Second");
    thread1.start();
    thread2.start();
}


public void run() {    
    runme();
```

}

```
public static synchronized void runme() {
    try {
    System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " has object a's key and waiting");
    Thread.sleep(1000);
    System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " Woke up from sleep"); 
    System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " wants b's Key"); 

    B.bs = 10;
    System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " over"); 

    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

public class B implements Runnable {

```
public static Integer bs = 6;

public void run() {
    runme();
}

public static synchronized void runme() {
    try {
        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " has object b's key and waiting");
        Thread.sleep(1000);
        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " Woke up from sleep");
        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " wants a's Key");

        A.as = 10;
        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " over");

    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

}

But getting below result:

Second has object b's key and waiting
First has object a's key and waiting
First Woke up from sleep
Second Woke up from sleep
Second wants a's Key
Second over
First wants b's Key
First over

Second thread is clearly editing the static variable of class A even when another thread holds the class level lock of class A

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can. Unless you have a *synchronized* block around the variable changing code. If you don't use *synchronization*, other threads don't have to acquire the `X.class`'s monitor before changing its *static_variable*.

Make the field `private`, and add a `setter`, make it *synchronized*, then you will not be able to change the field when another thread holds the lock for `X.class`